# New version of Premiere can't link files for old project because it's "type doesn't match"

Tags: premiere

I just opened a Premiere Pro project that I last worked on in December 2015. Since I have the new CC 2017 (PP v.11) installed, the usual dialogue came up that asked me to save a converted copy of the project for the current software version. I did so, after which the missing media dialogue came up (I moved a couple of folders around since last year). So I selected one of the clips and selected the corresponding file. This error message appeared:

[image: premiere pro link media error]

No idea why this is happening. They are the exact same files I used last year. They haven't been converted or anything. They haven't even been moved at all, all I did was rename the top folder containing them. It's the same computer, running the same OS (Win10). All that has changed is the version of Premiere Pro.

Is this a known issue? I searched for the error message but only found older threads with no real solution. Any leads on how to resolve it? Thanks!

**Edit:** I tried importing the files, which worked. However, they don't have any sound. Maybe it's an issue with some missing codecs?

Some exemplary MediaInfo output:

> General
>   Format                                   : MPEG-4
>   Format profile                           : Base Media
>   Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/3gp4)
>   File size                                : 15.9 MiB
>   Duration                                 : 7s 872ms
>   Overall bit rate                         : 16.9 Mbps
>   Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-11-06 16:15:36
>   Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-11-06 16:15:36
>
> Video
>   ID                                       : 1
>   Format                                   : AVC
>   Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
>   Format profile                           : High@L4
>   Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
>   Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
>   Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=30
>   Codec ID                                 : avc1
>   Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
>   Duration                                 : 7s 763ms
>   Bit rate                                 : 17.0 Mbps
>   Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
>   Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
>   Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
>   Frame rate mode                          : Variable
>   Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
>   Minimum frame rate                       : 29.412 fps
>   Maximum frame rate                       : 30.654 fps
>   Color space                              : YUV
>   Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
>   Bit depth                                : 8 bits
>   Scan type                                : Progressive
>   Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.273
>   Stream size                              : 15.7 MiB (99%)
>   Title                                    : VideoHandle
>   Language                                 : English
>   Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-11-06 16:15:36
>   Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-11-06 16:15:36
>   mdhd_Duration                            : 7763
>
> Audio
>   ID                                       : 2
>   Format                                   : AAC
>   Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
>   Format profile                           : LC
>   Codec ID                                 : 40
>   Duration                                 : 7s 872ms
>   Source duration                          : 8s 2ms
>   Source_Duration_FirstFrame               : 130ms
>   Bit rate mode                            : Constant
>   Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
>   Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
>   Channel positions                        : Front: L R
>   Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
>   Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 spf)
>   Compression mode                         : Lossy
>   Stream size                              : 120 KiB (1%)
>   Source stream size                       : 120 KiB (1%)
>   Title                                    : SoundHandle
>   Language                                 : English
>   Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-11-06 16:15:36
>   Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-11-06 16:15:36
>   mdhd_Duration                            : 7872